# The materials was lost in ios8, but ios 11 is work fine

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm using SceneKit in my app, and try to load the obj file(with mtl, jpg file) in the app.

I was developing in iOS11, everything work fine. but in iOS8, the materials was lost.

the following is the materials info in ios 8 and ios11, you can see the diff is the contents field, in iOS11, the contents field is only contain the filename, but in iOS8, it is a full path of the texture.

iOS 8:

```
    (lldb) po node.geometry?.materials
▿ Optional<Array<SCNMaterial>>
  ▿ some : 339 elements
    - 0 : <SCNMaterial: 0x174347bc0 '07___Default'
  diffuse=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x174347f30 | contents=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D985BE65-5657-4F35-8A80-769DE30280CF/MyApp.app/bump@3x.jpg>
  ambient=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x174346f60 | contents=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D985BE65-5657-4F35-8A80-769DE30280CF/MyApp.app/bump.jpg>
```

iOS 11:

```
      (lldb) po node.geometry?.materials
▿ Optional<Array<SCNMaterial>>
  ▿ some : 339 elements
    - 0 : <SCNMaterial: 0x1d01d6da0 '07___Default'
  diffuse=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1d00def40 | contents=bump@3x.jpg>
  ambient=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1d00deed0 | contents=bump.jpg>
  specular=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1d00df870 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.392344 0.392333 0.392339 1>
  emission=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1d00dfaa0 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1>
  transparent=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1d02c0070 | contents=1>
  reflective=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1d00dfdb0 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1>
  multiply=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1d00df8e0 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.999974 0.999991 1>
  normal=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1d00dfb10 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.999974 0.999991 1>
```

when debuging this problem, I've add @2x, @3x texture file to the project(both project three and default assets.xcassets), and I've also try change some geometry material in the xcode editor and save, still no materials in iOS 8.......

Please help, I've almost spended a day in this problem, no idea at all..

Comment: you have switch to Xcode-8  for iOS8 target?

Comment: Yes,it is iOS 8 deploy target, but I'm using Xcode 9.1